# Prevent Lync 2010/Skype for business from auto muting me when joining conference call

Tags: audio, skype, microphone, lync, lync-2010

So my headset at work has an inline switch to mute the microphone, which I've gotten into the habit of using to talk when doing conference calls. My employer has switched all conference calls to Lync/Skype for Business, which auto-mutes me whenever I join a conference call. Is there a setting to prevent it from auto-muting me? If there is, some help finding it would be appreciated.